# Creating standalone python app with py2app (.app is not opening and is too large)

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app

I am trying to convert my program into a .app file for distribution on macOS. However, once py2app has finished creating the .app version of the program it is currently a maximum size of 265.2 MB. My code is only 463 lines long so this seems unnecessarily large. Below are my imports.

```
from tkinter import Scrollbar, Frame, Canvas, Label, StringVar, font, Checkbutton, BooleanVar, Entry, Tk
from numpy import dot, linalg, vstack, ones, array
from scipy.stats import linregress
from math import log10, floor
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import use
```

I tried to reduce the size of the application by using `from * import *` with every module in the code. This didn't help, in fact it was worse (in terms of size). Without using the import method above, the application was 5 MB smaller???

And when I try to run the application I get the following error [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr6aW.png)

When I open console and search for the processes called "main" I get the following 5 messages (don't know whether this helps):

Message #1:

```
NSApp cache appearance:
-NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance: 1
-appearance: (null)
-effectiveAppearance: <NSCompositeAppearance: 0x600002c06180
 (
    "<NSAquaAppearance: 0x600002c04b00>",
    "<NSSystemAppearance: 0x600002c05080>"
)>
```

Message #2:

```
SignalReady: pid=12044 asn=0x0-0xf90f9
```

Message #3:

```
SIGNAL: pid=12044 asn=0x0x-0x1020153
```

Message #4:

```
LSExceptions shared instance invalidated for timeout.
```

Message #5:

```
AggregateDictionary is not supported on this platform
```

So I guess I have three questions:

1. Why is my application size so large?
2. How can I reduce the size?
3. Why is my app returning an error?

EDIT 1:

The problem is not with my computer. Tried creating the .app on another fresh mac (first time installing python on it).

Comment: Is this for making it for OS X?or for windows? Exe?

Comment: @CoolCloud For OS X. That's why I am using py2app